# template specialization for std::atomic<double> &

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have this MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atomic>

template<typename T> void assertVariableHasBeenSet( T, const char * );
template<>           void assertVariableHasBeenSet<std::atomic<double> &>
                                                        ( std::atomic<double> & myDouble, 
                                                          const char * variableName 
                                                        )
{
    printf( "Double:%s=%f\n", variableName,  myDouble.load() );
};

int main()
{
    std::atomic<double> myDoubleAtomic  {23.45};

    assertVariableHasBeenSet( myDoubleAtomic,   "myDoubleAtomic" );
}
```

I get this compiler error:

```
getType.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
getType.cpp:14:61: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic(const std::atomic<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = double]’
  assertVariableHasBeenSet( myDoubleAtomic, "myDoubleAtomic" );
                                                             ^
In file included from getType.cpp:2:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.4/atomic:169:7: note: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
       ^
getType.cpp:4:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void assertVariableHasBeenSet(T, const char*) [with T = std::atomic<double>]’
```

How can I pass a `std::atomic<double>` reference to the specialized template?
In a normal function it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case, `T` will be deduced as `std::atomic<double>`, not `std::atomic<double> &`. Then the primary template will always be invoked instead of the specialization.

You can specify the template argument explicitly, e.g.

```
assertVariableHasBeenSet<std::atomic<double> &>(myDoubleAtomic, "myDoubleAtomic");
```

Or apply overloading.

```
template<typename T> void assertVariableHasBeenSet( T, const char * );

void assertVariableHasBeenSet( std::atomic<double> & myDouble, 
                               const char * variableName 
                             )
{
    printf( "Double:%s=%f\n", variableName,  myDouble.load() );
}
```

Comment: I understand now! I took your 2nd edit with the overloaded template! I don't want to specifiy [e.q. give the compiler the hint] what to use! +1

Comment: @AlBundy Yes function template overloading is quite fine and handy for most cases so don't forget it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here:

```
template<typename T> void assertVariableHasBeenSet( T, const char * );
```

The primary template will be chosen because `myDoubleAtomic` is of type `std::atomic<double>`, not `std::atomic<double> &`.

The primary template tries to pass `T` by value, requiring a copy. `std::atomic` has a deleted copy constructor resulting in that error.

You should tell the compiler what type to use explicitly :

```
assertVariableHasBeenSet<std::atomic<double> &>(myDoubleAtomic,   "myDoubleAtomic" );
```

Comment: Yeah Rick, your _You should tell the compiler what type to use explicitly_ has lighted up the situation. I prefer the template overload! +1 Thx

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to happen is overload resolution. During overload resolution the type `T` is deduced as `std::atomic<double>`. Next the proper specialisation is determined. There is no specialised version and the primary template is used. The specialisation for `std::atomic<double>&` will never be found by deduction.

There are two approaches to fix the problem (I don’t consider specifying the type explicitly a solution):

1. Declare the primary template to take a forwarding reference `T&&` as this would deduce `T` as `std::atomic<double>&`.
2. Instead of template specialisation use overloading, i.e., remove the `template<>` and the `<std::atomic<double>&>` after the function name.